# C programming why isnt my code working?

Tags: c

So,I have to write a code for `S=1+1*2+1*2*3+1*2*3*4+..n!` where n is given by the user.
I wrote this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    int i, n, j, s, p;
    printf("Put a number:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    s = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++);    
    {
     p=1;    
    }

   for (j=1;j<=i;j++)
   {
       s=s+(p*i);
   }
   printf("\n Sum=%d",s);
   return 0;
}
```

It compiles, but when I run it and put for example: 2, the result is 9 when it should be 3. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `for (i=1;i<=n;i++);` - remove `;`

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: `for (i=1;i<=n;i++);` now that's one long winded way of saying `i=n+1`

Comment: I removed it but the problem is logical,not in the syntax,

Comment: Also, you should always test that `scanf()` returns the expected value for the number of converted inputs, `1` in this case.

Comment: Is this homework? If yes, consider tagging it as such...

Comment: @SdasdSdaf Keep it simple OP, use `recursion`.It's better,easier and it doesn't take that much effort to understand what `recursion` is.

Comment: I am amazed so many people never bothered to compile their code before posting it for the OP.So full of errors!!.

Comment: @xgbi: The homework tag was officially burninated: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: @LnxPrgr3: Wow! That's why I didn's see so many HW questions tagged correctly ... I should spend more time on meta.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need

```
int f = 1;
int s = 0;
for (i = 1;i <= n;i++)
{     
    f *= i;
    s += f;
}
```

But i would suggest you look at your own code with a debugger to learn how things are working

Edit:

`for (i=1;i<=n;i++);` is equivalent to `i = n+1`

The block here is useless, you're just setting p to 1;

```
{
 p=1;    
}
```

In the following i is always `n+1` and `p` is always 1, so you are effectively doing `i+i+i...` for n times

```
for (j=1;j<=i;j++)
{
   s=s+(p*i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ; after the first "for" ends the statement, so that's an empty loop. Also, the second loop should be inside the first one and it's not. Indenting the code isn't just cosmetic--it can help clarify code like this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you write a function that calculates factorial(n) first, then you use that function in a loop.

It'll be easier to understand.

```
int fact( int n) {
   // do your factorial compututation
}

int n = 0, sum = 0;

scanf("%d", &n);

for( int i = 0; i<n; i++) 
{
   sum += fact(i);
}
```

The code you present has several flaws in it:

- `for (i=1;i<=n;i++);` is simply doing `i = n;`; I don't think that's what you want to do
- even if this loop was correct, the body of your for, `{ p=1; }` will assign 1 to `p` at each iteration. That's not what you want either I think.
- I'd suggest trying for yourself by taking a paper and a pen and step in your program to see what's happening at each step. You should have designed your algorithm on paper before trying to write it in C.

For optimization, here's your mathematical problem:

[image]

On the 2nd line, if you keep `prev = n!`, you'll see that in your for loop you can optimize the fact(i) by doing:

```
int prev = 1;
int sum = 0;
for( int i = 1; i<n; i++) // start at 1 to skip the first iteration where 0! = 1
{
   sum += prev;
   prev = prev * i; // compute next factorial
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think basically it need two loops, one for adding the factorial value, and an inner loop for calculating the factorial.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){
        int i,n,j,sum,factorial;
        printf("Put a number:");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        sum = 0;
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
                factorial = 1;
                for (j=2;j<=i;j++){
                        factorial *= j;
                }
                sum += factorial;
        }
        printf("\nSum=%d\n",sum);
        return 0;
}
```

But we can find that we don't need to calculate the factorial from 1 every time, because we can get factorial(n) from factorial(n - 1). So:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){
        int i,n,j,sum,factorial;
        printf("Put a number:");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        sum = 0;
        factorial = 1;
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
                factorial *= i;
                sum += factorial;
        }
        printf("\nSum=%d\n",sum);
        return 0;
}
```

Also, you should do it better on code style and naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the main logic behind this program : `Use a recursive function to calculate the factorial of n,and use this within a for loop to calculate the summation for all values between 1 and n`:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int factorial(int);

int main(void)
  {
   int i,n,s;
   printf("Put a number:");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   s=0;

     for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
     {
       s+=factorial(i);
     }
  printf("\n Sum=%d",s);

  }

int factorial(int x)
  {

    if(x==1)
    return 1;    
    return x*factorial(x-1);

  }
```

In your program the following piece of code serves no purpose at all:

```
for (i=1;i<=n;i++);    
    {
     p=1;    
    }
```

Further you don't need so many variables for the job.Using recursion makes it all the more simple and elegant, and if you doing it for an assignment, you can impress your teacher more if you can do it the smarter way.Using `for` loops only for the whole thing will make things messy.

Comment: Your program's indentation is ugly as hell :-)

Comment: @Jens OK,formatted it.But I had to do it manually for each line.Do you know how to auto-format a whole program in the text editor at once?I only know the "code sample" option which simply highlights the selected text as code.How to format the whole thing at once?

Comment: Thanks. I recommend **GNU indent** to indent code on your computer and then pasting it. The edit pane has no indent capability for a particular programming language.

Comment: @Jens GNU indent is a program available to download for windows?

Comment: @Jens I had assumed you would edit my answer yourself as you have enough reputation for that.Or you need more for editing other's answers?

Comment: @Jens The setup file I downloaded from the GNU site simply loads pdfs, no program!!Even the link from the startup menu is only to pdfs and documentation,none to the program.I have faced this issue with all GNU or open-source stuff.One only gets Zip files which contains folders with dll etc.I am only used to downloading stand-alone `exe` files for Windows that only expect us to click `next,next`....I need your suggestion how to make this GNU indent thingie work

Comment: How am I to know you're on Windows? There's more than one OS out there. But anyway, use the GNUWIN32 version of indent, http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/indent.htm

Comment: @Jens The program seems to work only from a command-line!!I had expected something straight and simple like a GUI with a window where I would simply paste the code and get the formatted code.Know something like that?

Comment: It doesn't get much more straight and simple than a command line utility. I have integrated it in `vi`/`vim` where I can filter a file through an arbitrary program with a single keypress. Maybe your IDE allows the same. What about a new question "How can I integrate GNUwin32 indent on Windows?"

Answer (score 0):

Basically everything was wrong :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int factorial(int n)
{
    int i, res = 1;

    for(i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        res *= i;

    return res;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, n, s = 0;
    printf("Put a number:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    s = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        s += factorial(i);

    printf("\n Sum=%d\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So i copied you code, compiled in gcc, called `time a.out` and gave a input of 999999, went to bathroom, came back, went for a drink, came back, then pressed CTRL+C, the results were still being calculated, then again called `./a.out` now gave input`
    Put a number:d
    Sum=-125961703`
:)  (Just kidding, code is fine for normal input, and nice logic)

Comment: Too bad he gave the factorial code.. I guess that was the subject of the homework..